# Reactjs sending prop to child that is handed from Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a following render function in my top most component App:

```
render() {
  const { content } = this.props;
  return (
      <div id="content">
        {content}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The {content} variable is delivered from Routes like this:

```
export default (
    <Router history={History}>
        <Route path={UserConstants.HOME_ROUTE} component={App}>
            <IndexRoute components={{content:HomePage}}/>
            <Route path={UserConstants.LOGIN_ROUTE} components=}{content:LoginPage}} />
    </Router>
    )
```

How can I add props from the parent App to the {content} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App, instead of `{content}` use

```
{React.cloneElement(content, {
     myProp: 'value'
  })}
```

And `myProp` will be accessible in the child component in `this.props.myProp` .

You can make this more dynamic to work with different child components if you use

```
{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
     myProp: 'value'
  })}
```

Comment: This works a bit. The content component loads but no lifecycle event triggers the prop given to it by his parent. ComponentWillUpdate/DidUpdate or Mount does nothing with the prop ...